# would there be any reason to hash a GUID?

Tags: hash, guid

would there be any reason to hash a GUID?

Comment: Perhaps if not hashing it would be too much trouble.

Comment: the question is really meaningless. You can ask also why to hash string or int. It is wrong. The question is meaningful if you ask should i hash passwords? or any other data. GUID is not data but datatype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it fit into a 32-bit int? That's what many hash-table implementations work with.

Comment: not all hashes are 32 bit. btw, this is not answer, but a comment.

Comment: @Andrey, can you explain why this is not an answer?

Comment: question was: would there be reason... I don't see any reasons in your answer plus a false assumption that all hashes are 32 bits

Answer (score 1):

The only possible use of it if you use those GUIDs as security tokens or something like passwords. If your DB was broken hackers will not be able to use tokens because they are hashed.